# What is this barrel-shaped component in my bathtub drain plumbing?

Tags: plumbing

I have a part on a tub drain where the water from the tub enters low but then exits higher to go to the stack. It says St Louis Eclipse on the part. Currently the tub will not drain.[image]

Comment: Betting the problem is inside, and you are not happy about taking the top off and placing your hand inside to clean it out, are you?  It looks like a bad design sewer gas trap.

Comment: Looks like someone tried to take it off but didn't come off.

Comment: Looks like a "Bottle Trap" to me.

Comment: A Bottle Trap necks down like a bottle and the pipe goes out the top. Also prohibited now.

Comment: @Ecnerwal I think bottle traps are still used in Britain for sinks based on some other threads here.  They don't require as much horizontal space as a p-trap.

Answer (score 27):

That's a **drum trap.**

To the best of my knowledge they are no longer allowed. [*Which in typical fashion means you can clear the clog if you choose to and keep using it, but replacement if needed must be a currently approved trap type. They are prone to clogging and prone to the clogs being prone to making you retch - as well as being prone to have the access cover refuse to move.*]

IPC 1002.3 (Prohibited traps) Point 6 (unless being used as a solids interceptor or for chemical waste systems.)

Replace with a P-trap.

Comment: https://www.finehomebuilding.com/project-guides/plumbing/mystery-plumbing-find

Comment: I've had a few of these.  The worst part is that they are really tough to snake.  Every time I've tried, the snake just coils up in there.  I've had plumbers do it successfully but they won't tell me the secret.

Comment: Snaking that seems like it would be truly maddening...